# Need help.I ws trying to create a form inside another component in Angular. Aftr Importing ReactiveFormBulider module it threw NG8001 error

Tags: angular

app.module.ts

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { **AddproductComponent** } from './component/addproduct/addproduct.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProductComponent,
    ContentLimitterPipe,
    **AddproductComponent**,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
```

added part to main component

```
  <section class="col-md-5" *ngIf="showproduct">
            <app-addproduct></app-addproduct>
           </section>strong text
```

After the compilations process .It throws NG8001 error>Nevertheless, this occurred only in this component .I tried the same code in a another Angular project and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The [`NG8001`](https://angular.io/errors/NG8001) error refers to

> Unknown HTML element or component

So the selector in your `AddproductComponent` decorator is not set to `app-addproduct`

Comment: ,Sry I forgot to mention it. The selector was set to app-addproduct.                                                 `@Component({
  selector: 'app-addproduct',
  templateUrl: './addproduct.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./addproduct.component.css']
})`